# How to serve static files with django that has hardcoded relative paths on Heroku/OpenShift/etc?

Tags: django, heroku, paas

I have HTML/JS/CSS files provided by a third party (whom I have no control over) that serves as a single page app that communicates with a backend built with Django and django-rest-framework.

I'm wanting to host this on Heroku and thus these static assets are being served by Django.  These files contains relative paths to each other.  For example, the index.html contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Which leads to a 404 because `styles/css/bootstrap.min.css` is not routed by django.

The only way I know of to serve the index.html from my domain root `www.domain.com` is with an url config like:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
```

...even though it's not really a template, it's just plain HTML.

The problem arises from the fact that all the urls in the other assets are relative to this `index.html` and of course Django doesn't work like that.  If I was developing this front-end application I'd be using the `static` template tag and one of the various ways to get urls to javascript.

I don't mind switching from Heroku to another PaaS if they offer a solution to this problem, but manually editing all these files does not sound like a fun job...especially considering the fact that I'll be receiving updates to these files going forward.

I *think* the way to solve this on a regular old server would be to configure the web server to resolve these urls correctly, but that option doesn't seem to be available on Heroku.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how to set up Django to serve your static files and index.html on / while still having the possibility to use Django views for the admin dashboard, registration etc.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

    # / routes to index.html
    url(r'^$', serve,
        kwargs={'path': 'index.html'}),

    # static files (*.css, *.js, *.jpg etc.) served on /
    # (assuming Django uses /static/ and /media/ for static/media urls)
    url(r'^(?!/?static/)(?!/?media/)(?P<path>.*\..*)$',
        RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/%(path)s', permanent=False)),

    # other views still work too
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

I specify `urlpatterns` as a list, as Django 1.10 requires. The redirects are [not permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706497/544059) by default since 1.9, so you need to explicitly set `permanent=True` if you want browsers to cache this, though when debugging I find it better to start with `False`.

This approach allows you to use something like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) or [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) frontend generators that package a built, minified frontend app into a single folder (like *dist/*). You then e.g. use a script to move that into Django's static files folder (e.g. *myproject/static/*) and serve it from Heroku.

What Ian wrote about wanting to use something like S3 for your static files stands, but sometimes you just want to start simple with one repository, one Heroku dyno and still be able to use Django + a SPA. Also, using something like [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) makes serving static files from Python pretty OK and allows you to 
later on [easily put a CDN](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#use-a-content-delivery-network) in front of your static files.

**Note:** for user-uploaded files you should still use an outside service like Amazon S3 or Backblaze B2 (which is 4 lines of code to [integrate](https://github.com/royendgel/django-backblazeb2-storage)).

> #### Serving Media Files
>
> WhiteNoise is not suitable for serving user-uploaded “media” files. For one thing, as described above, it only checks for static files at startup and so files added after the app starts won’t be seen. More importantly though, serving user-uploaded files from the same domain as your main application is a security risk ([this blog post](https://security.googleblog.com/2012/08/content-hosting-for-modern-web.html) from Google security describes the problem well). And in addition to that, using local disk to store and serve your user media makes it harder to scale your application across multiple machines.
>
> For all these reasons, it’s much better to store files on a separate dedicated storage service and serve them to users from there. The [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library provides many options e.g. Amazon S3, Azure Storage, and Rackspace CloudFiles.

**Note 2:** on production with `DEBUG=False` there are issues, so check out [this WhiteNoise issue](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/12) for a solution.

**Note 3:** *Turned this answer into a blog post [here](https://metakermit.com/2016/simple-way-to-set-up-django-a-spa-frontend-on-heroku/).*

**Note 4:** since writing this, I've been tweaking the solution more and more for frontend routing, so I ended up releasing a new [django-spa](https://github.com/metakermit/django-spa) package suited for simple serving of single-page apps from Django.

Comment: I'm learning angular with django rest framework and man this saved me from hours of frustation :)

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari glad you found it useful. Let me know if you run into problems with the method :)